# omprog does not capture script output to file

Tags: rsyslog

I've got a problem where the `omprog` module of `rsyslog` doesn't seem to be using the `output` parameter to capture the script's output to file.  What am I doing wrong?

My `rsyslog` server receives a dozen syslog messages per second from an external host, and i want a certain task to occur when any message meets a particular criteria.  So, I wrote a Python script that scans for the particular criteria on `stdin` and performs the task.  (This task fires about once every couple hours.)  For all other messages, the Python script discards the message and continues listening.  The Python script runs infinitely while the pipe is open.  This much works perfectly.

Then, I added a few confirmation messages into the Python script so that it will output a "started" message to `stdout` when it launches, and output a "done" message to `stdout` when the task happens.  I set `omprog`'s `confirmMessages` parameter to `off`, and the `output` parameter to a file within `/var/log`.  The output of `getenforce` tells me that SELinux is off.  When I restart `rsyslog`, the file is never created, and the output is never captured.

So, I `touch`ed the file as the syslog user, and restarted `rsyslog`, but that doesn't fix it.  Doing a `systemctl status rsyslog` shows that the Python script is running.  And I can confirm that the particular is getting executed when the script sees the particular message.

Running the Python script manually does produce output and sits there infinitely until I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>.

I also configured the Python script output to `stderr` instead of `stdout` just to see if that made a difference.  After restarting `rsyslog`, there was still no output file.

System: `Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS`

rsyslogd: `version 8.2001.0`

rsyslog config:

```
module(load="omprog")
if $fromhost-ip == '10.200.25.5'     then {
  action(type="omfile"
    file="/var/log/network")
  action(type="omprog"
    name="rsyslog_watch_vpn_attach"
    binary="/usr/share/rsyslog/watch_syslog_vpn_attach.py"
    confirmMessages="off"
    output="/var/log/watch_vpn_attach.log")
  stop
}
```

The `/var/log/network` file is building.  The `/var/log/watch_vpn_attach.log` file is not building.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably just a problem of buffering in the Python program. A simple solution is to make sure you add `flush=True` in the print statements, eg:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3
import sys,time
for data in sys.stdin:
    print(f"got data at {time.asctime()}: {data}",flush=True)
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I even let the script run for a full day and it never "flushed" by itself. Adding the parameter fixed it. I thought the problem belonged to `rsyslog` because it didn't create an empty file when i restarted the service. I really appreciate your help!